# Is there any form to reduce the quantity of messages read per second from PubSubIO?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a cloud streaming pipeline that read from PubSubIO and which "PipelineOptions" are set with "WorkerMachineType = n1-standard-1". This machine have 3.75GB of memory.

My problem is that if the subscription has a lot of messages, the pipeline reads really fast and when starts to process many elements it doesn't have enough memory.

Is there any form to reduce the quantity of messages read per second? or is the memory consumption related with the time duration assigned to the window and I would reduce this time duration?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Can you please answer a few clarifying questions? 
1. Are you seeing crashes or high memory usage? 
2. Can you also provide a few more details about what you're doing in this pipeline (type of windowing, triggers, discarding/accumulating fired panes mode, overall throughput in records/sec and bytes/sec)?
3. How many workers do you have allocated?

Comment: Hi Tyler, following you can find the answers to your questions:
1- The pipeline doesn't crash, 10 minutes after I've executed the pipeline, I see high memory usage and the pipeline seems as if it was paused so after the window duration time it doesn't write anything.
2- In this pipeline I apply 30 minmutes window (without triggers) and then I do a GroupByKey. The pipeline reads messages from PubSubIO with a throughput of 46-65 messages/second and processes elements with a throughput of 60000-100000 elements/second.
3- I have only one worker allocated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may be trying to process too much data with too few workers. We are looking at addressing this and related scenarios, but in the meantime you may want to try dialing down the amount of data you're ingesting, or increasing the number of workers available to the jobs.

You'll also get better performance with [n1-standard-4](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) machines, which is why we make those the [default](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/faq#question-1) for the streaming runner.